# Skype Bandwidth usage for online teaching

Tags: skype, bandwidth

We are online teaching via skype, we use Video and screen sharing. We have 15 Teachers.

Details of our Data we have up to 1.75 mbps data speed from our ISP.

This is our problem everyday if all 15 teachers engage in their students some connection drop, every teacher have 30 mins. of session per student

How much bandwidth do we need to prevent the connection drop?

Answer (score 0):

Here are [some Skype bandwidth usage numbers](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1417/how-much-bandwidth-does-skype-need):

[image: Screenshot of official Skype bandwidth numbers.]

You are most likely experiencing the connection drops due to the upload speed.

According to the chart, you would need 2Mbps Download, and 4.5Mbps Upload to support all 15 connections.

Therefore you want to look for a package that supports the upload speed of 5Mbps or more.

Comment: thanks Cosco Tech, forgot to include we have up to 1.75mbps bursting to 14 mbps. even if we have bursting to 14 mbps?

Comment: Bursting is based on line usage, so if there is high traffic in your area that day, you might burst no higher than 1.75. I believe you are talking about the download speed, what upload speed do you have.

Comment: using this speed test "speedtest.net" sometimes we have 18mbps or less, and if we use the preffered speed testing of our client the frontier speed test we get 2mbps or 0.03mbps, when all the teachers are engage into their students.